# Automatically populating Components in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on my Final Year Project and have been stuck in a problem for last 1 month and it is giving me sleepless nights. It's a Test Creating and Online Test taking application. Each Question is   stored in Data Base. How can i automatically populate different Net Beans properties according to the type of the Question. for example Combo boxes for each MCQs and Radio Buttons for T/F Type Questions.I mean Automatically creation and Population of  components.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to as proper questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a JPanel to your design that is the correct size for components you want to change dynamically. Select the JPanel and right-click for a pop-up context menu. Select `Set Layout` -> `CardLayout`. Now when you drag components onto that JPanel instead of showing them  in different positions they will just stack on top of each other. You can see the list of components you have added in the Navigator tree. You will only be able to see the top one in the design itself. Select each in the Navigator and edit its property for `Card Name` in the Layout section near the bottom. The name is probably card1 or card2 etc. Change it to something you can remember for when you write the code below.

Then you would put code like this whenever you need to change the displayed component.

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) this.jPanel1.getLayout();
cl.show(jPanel1, "checkboxcard");
```

"checkboxcard" was the name previously set as the Card Name property.

The embedded components do not have to be simple swing controls. You could create several JPanel designs and drag them into the parent jpanel with the cardlayout. For each internal panel, select your project and select New -> `JPanel Form` to create a new panel you can design. Compile the corresponding class and then drag it from the Project tab to the design with the parent jpanel.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave me a good idea and i have solved the problem. Thanks!